# Can I use IN method in LIKE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which stores a set of questions. Each question linked with a minimum of 1 and maximum of 3 subjects.

```
QUESTION_TABLE
---------------
id          => INT (primary key)
question    => VARCHAR
subject1    => VARCHAR
subject2    => VARCHAR
subject3    => VARCHAR
created_at  => DATETIME
```

A subject is stored as a combination of subject, section and chapter with a comma `,` separated. Here are some examples of my data.

```
| id |  question   | subject1 | subject2 | subject3 |     created_at     | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | some text.. |  1,      | 17,      |  9,33,5  | 2019-01-12 11:45:26
| 2  | some text.. | 17,22,98 |  1,      | 12,10    | 2019-02-22 15:23:10
| 3  | some text.. |  9,33    |          |          | 2019-03-13 12:04:43
| 4  | some text.. | 17,      |  5,      |  1,      | 2019-04-05 05:30:12
```

I need to get the question with subjects linked with `[1,17,5]` where these are dynamic data. For that I use below query.

```
SELECT * FROM questions
WHERE subject1 LIKE '1,%'  OR subject2 LIKE '1,%'  OR subject3 LIKE '1,%'
 OR   subject1 LIKE '17,%' OR subject2 LIKE '17,%' OR subject3 LIKE '17,%'
 OR   subject1 LIKE '5,%'  OR subject2 LIKE '5,%'  OR subject3 LIKE '5,%'
```

There will be 3 senario of searching.
 * **subject,section and chapter** `LIKE '17,22,98`
 * **subejct and section** `LIKE '17,22,%'`
 * **subejct only** `LIKE '17,%'`

Is there any other way to reduce this complexity in the query? Can I use `IN` method in `LIKE` statement?

**Note**: I can't change the way of structure. The project is already implemented by another user and I don't have much time to change the structure. So please, understand the situation.

Comment: may be you r looking for `find_in_set`

Comment: If in subject1 there is only 1 value is there a comma at the end, or is it a typo?

Comment: So there is no '1,' or '17,' but  '1' and '17'.

Comment: @forpas: No. it's not a typo. Each value represents, the first value is `subject` and the second one is `section` and the final one is `chapter`. If there is only a `subject` it becomes `17,`. Using the comma `,` and the position we detecting the subject, section and chapter `id`

Comment: *Is there any other way to reduce this complexity in the query?* Yep, there is: *Normalize your data model.*

Comment: @dnoeth: It can't. As like I mentioned it's implemented by another user and there are lots of condition which using this structure. So it's not easy to change the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RegExp with OR condition

```
SELECT * FROM QUESTION_TABLE
WHERE subject1 REGEXP  "^(1|17|5),+"
OR subject2 REGEXP  "^(1|17|5),+"
OR subject3 REGEXP  "^(1|17|5),+";
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/38edTCm33XHkjQpiNC9woy/2)

You can change RegExp according to your requirement

e.g for subject 17 and section 22  then `REGEXP  ('^17,22,+')`

Comment: These seem to be two-digit values with a leading space, switch to `WHERE subject1 REGEXP '( 1|17| 5),+'` instead

Comment: Ya. I also tried with `REGEXP`. But this may cause an error when  `22,11,555`.

Comment: I also tried with this `subject1 REGEXP  ('^([1][7]|[1]|[5]),')` and got exact result. Do you have any better solution?

Comment: @Nishal I think it not detect `7,` check here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/38edTCm33XHkjQpiNC9woy/4

Comment: it will not result when I search `9,33,5`. For that, I think we need to search like `subject1 REGEXP ( '^(17,|1,|9,33,5)+' )`

Comment: here 9 33 5 all are subject ? or subject,section,chapter

Comment: 9 - Subject, 33 - Section. 5 - Chapter. if subject, section and chapter are existed then `9,33,5`. There will not be a comma `,` at the end. That's why I added in my result as `subject1 REGEXP ( '^(17,|1,|9,33,5)+' )`

Comment: yes, that's why I added e.g in my answer, according to your requirement you can change the regex. I only provide the answer for  subject 1|17|5  your above answer is correct if there 17|1| 9,33,5

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `find_in_set()`

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE find_in_set(subject1,(1,17,5))>0 
OR find_in_set(subject2,(1,17,5))>0 OR find_in_set(subject3,(1,17,5))>0
```

Comment: Sorry. This does not work because I need to search with the string starting with `1,` or `17,` or `5,`

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution using `REGEXP`

```
SELECT * FROM questions
WHERE subject1 REGEXP  ('^(17,|1,|5,)+')
 OR   subject2 REGEXP  ('^(17,|1,|5,)+')
 OR   subject3 REGEXP  ('^(17,|1,|5,)+')
```

Does anyone have a better solution?
it's not easy to generate this query if there a scenario with a search of `17,255,303` or `1405,555,`

Comment: Change `+` *at least one char* to `*` *zero or more chars* `REGEXP  '^(17,255,303|1405,555,|5,)*'`